# Configure dispatcher Servlet to connect to other host

Tags: java, file, unix, upload, dispatcher

I have an upload program which uploads file and saves it to the specified host on which this application is deployed.

I want to save this files to other host.
Can someone guide me what changes I must do to my dispatcher servlet for the same or any other alternate?

Comment: Can you show us some code and describe what you have tried?

Comment: This question is far too broad! What exactly is your 'dispatcher servlet'? How do you want to connect to the remote host (HTTP, FTP, CIFS, etc.)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Would advice to open a new connection with the other host within the Servlet and upload the file using the connection.

```
 int contentChar = null;
 FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getfileRootDir()+ "/"+fileId));

 URL oracle = new URL("other server url");
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 OutputStream outPutStream = connection.getOutputStrea()
 while ((contentChar = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
      outPutStream.write(contentLine );
 }
 inputStream .close();
 outPutStream.close(); 
 connection.close();
```

If you want to use BufferredReader/Writer from efficiency perspective, you may want to write as below:

```
   String contentLine = null;
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new FileReader(getfileRootDir()+ "/"+fileId));

   URL oracle = new URL("other server url");
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   OutputStream outPutStream = connection.getOutputStrea()
   Writer streamWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outPutStream ));
   while ((contentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        streamWriter.write(contentLine );
   }
   reader.close();       
   streamWriter.close();
   outPutStream .close(); 
   connection.close();
```

Comment: You are doing this with one simple java code. This can be run stand alone as well. Don't see any issue.

Comment: @artbristol : Is it not that character encoding is taken care with the content being passed to write?

Comment: <property name="fileRootDir"><value>/test/upload/files</value></property>
        <property name="fileRootURL"><value>../files</value></property>        -------------------------------------------------------------------This is what i am using now..i.e. path in dispatcher servlet

Comment: There is no need to use a `Writer` here. Just write the bytes of the file directly to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: <property name="fileRootDir"><value>abcd.xxx.com:8080/test/upload/files</value></property>
        <property name="fileRootURL"><value>../files</value></property> ---------------- here if u see abcd.xxx.com:8080/ ... i need my files to be uploaded at other host which is abcd...and this is what i assumed it should be.. as i want my files to be uploaded to other host..

Comment: I am saying, do not dispatch your request to the other host. Keep it within your current host servlet. Write the above code to establish the connection and upload the file.

Comment: @artbristol: I agree that `BufferredWriter` is not mandatory but its added from efficiency perspective.

Comment: Yes. In one of the classes in the request processing path of current host.

Comment: in controller class iam using File file1=new File(getfileRootDir()+ "/"+fileId);

Comment: @YogendraSingh using a `Writer` on a byte stream will mangle the results, sometimes but not always, so the code might appear to work at first. Please, update your answer to remove it. And read http://kunststube.net/encoding/.

Comment: I believe this will read the input file. You can use this file `file1` object to write the data through out stream. I am updating the answer with couple additional steps. Please refer,

Comment: @artbristol I updated the answer. If you feel it is good, may you want to remove your -1.

Comment: Thanks for the update but you're still recommending using a `Writer`, which is going to mangle binary files from time to time. Why not suggest using commons-io's `IOUtils.copy`?

Comment: @artbristol: Thanks for your inputs. My idea was to share the basic concept as to use the connection from first server to second server and proceed `to answer the real question`. Your valuable inputs regarding character encoding are available on this page, which may help the OP/users.

Comment: hi guys,Thanks for your suggestions .i shared the location of host and local path of attachments.Problem resolved

Comment: @Angel491: Good to know, your problem is resolved. If you think that answer was helpful, please don't forget to accept.